# netlogo: how to move turtles with different colors towards patches with same colors

Tags: netlogo

I am a new Netlogo learner. I want to make my turtles moving towards patches together. Each turtle finds the patch with same color. Every turtle moves one step per tick. I also plan to add a status to each turtle, showing how many more steps it need to get to the right patch. My current code is:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patch 0 0 [ set pcolor 5 ]
  ask patch -5 0 [ set pcolor 15 ]
  ask patch 5 0 [ set pcolor 25 ]
  ask patch -10 0 [ set pcolor 35 ]
  ask patch 10 0 [ set pcolor 45 ]
  ask patch -15 0 [ set pcolor 55 ]
  ask patch 15 0 [ set pcolor 65 ]
  ask patch -20 0 [ set pcolor 75 ]
  ask patch 20 0 [ set pcolor 85 ]
  crt-turtle
  reset-ticks
end

to crt-turtle
  create-turtles 1000
  ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor 
    set shape "car" 
    set color one-of [ 5 15 25 35 45 55 65 75 85 ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    face min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = 35 ] [ distance myself ]
    forward 1
  ]
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may find it helpful to ask a question and explain what is not working as you intended it to. Currently, you are simply making a statement about what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  Just change that `35` to `[color] of myself`, or to be a bit more explicit:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    let _mycolor color
    face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = _mycolor] [distance myself]
    forward 1
  ]
end
```